# Setting TRadioButton to checked causes OnClick event

Tags: delphi

```
mybox.Checked := true;
```

Setting TRadioButton to checked (by code)  causes OnClick event handler to be called.

How can I recognize if user is making the state change   by GUI interaction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can nil the OnClick event handler while changing a radiobutton state programmatically:

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Save: TNotifyEvent;

begin
  Save:= RadioButton2.OnClick;
  RadioButton2.OnClick:= nil;
  RadioButton2.Checked:= not RadioButton2.Checked;
  RadioButton2.OnClick:= Save;
end;
```

Comment: Ideally you should wrap this in a try..finally if there was any more complex logic between `OnClick := nil` and `OnClick := Save;`

Answer (score 4):

```
 mybox.Tag := 666; 
 mybox.Checked :=true; 
 mybox.Tag := 0;

procedure myboxOnclick(Sender : TObject);
begin
if Tag = 0 then
//Do your thing
end;
```

Comment: I favor this approach but usually use an flag in the private section of the form class, something along the lines of "ChangingStuffRomCode:Boolean". The idea's that there usually are multiple radio buttons (and other controls that behave like this) and it's simpler to do set a single flag when initializing the form.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an action connected to the radiobutton, you can set the checked property of the action instead. This will also prevent the OnClick event to be fired.

Comment: But if you're using actions, you're probably using the action's OnExecute event, not the control's OnClick event. Does OnExecute get fired when you change the action's Checked property?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: No, it does not - Action.OnExecute and Button.OnClick is the same event here. An action temporally sets the radiobutton's protected 'ClicksDisabled' property to True to prevent radiobutton's 'OnClick' event to fire while changing 'Checked' property.

Answer (score 0):

`TRadioButton` (like [`TCheckBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264351/change-checkbox-state-without-calling-onclick-event/2264590#2264590)) provides a protected property `ClicksDisabled` that can help you.

I use class helpers to add the needed functionality:

```
RadioButton1.SetCheckedWithoutClick(False);
```

with the following class helper for a VCL `TRadioButton`:

```
TRadioButtonHelper = class helper for TRadioButton
    procedure SetCheckedWithoutClick(AChecked: Boolean);
end;

procedure TRadioButtonHelper.SetCheckedWithoutClick(AChecked: Boolean);
begin
    ClicksDisabled := True;
    try
        Checked := AChecked;
    finally
        ClicksDisabled := False;
    end;
end;
```